# Lost 235 rep due to user removal

Tags: discussion

Is there any tidy way to let me know which user was removed? That's a pretty big hit to take from one user's removal. Just curious.

Comment: This seems related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328642/280883 and probably the cause why https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18644/367990 was asked.

Comment: I lost 420, so you're not alone.

Comment: @DKBose "site:askubuntu.com 497767" doesn't seem to show anything. Am I typing it incorrectly?

Comment: AU giveth and AU taketh away. -98 for me.

Comment: @Pilot6 I beat you by **5**, I lost 425 :)

Comment: lost over 500 on space stack exchange :)

Comment: 130 lost  here...

Comment: Aside from the lost rep, one issue is that [there is no way to prevent one's questions from being removed by roomba (Stack Exchange's automated question deletion system) after a user was removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281124/178179).

Comment: -110 for me  :-(

Answer (score 22):

Nope, sorry. This wasn't done by us (the AU mods), but by an SE employee, and they aren't telling. And correctly so. There are obvious privacy concerns involved. [This is all we got](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328644/203101):

> One or more users deleted their profiles, and there's really not anything further we can discuss about the topic for privacy reasons.

I get that you're curious (I am too) but I also accept that users have the right to delete their accounts and not have that announced publicly. So I doubt we'll ever know more details.

Comment: GDPR: *The right to be forgotten*...

Comment: terdon- is there any maintenance running in background to deleting some kind of users? because I'm thinking how is it possible for a single user deletion that much reputation losing from most users here, I think it's not only for a single user deletion and might there is some clean up task by community developers, mods knows that?

Comment: @αғsнιη as far as we know, no. But it isn't hard at all for a single user to cause so much havoc. [This is the list of our top voters](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all). Everyone on the first page there has cast thousands of votes. There's even [one user](https://askubuntu.com/users/563903/gnat) who has never posted anything here and yet has cast a total of 9,170 votes! If that user's votes were deleted, that would remove a total of 53,810 reputation points shared between multiple users.

Comment: @terdon- wait, I see 6,704 votes from that user (currently), how you see it was  9,170?!  maybe what I see is only for up-votes?