# is it possible to know on which Question or Answer the reputation change occured in case of "User was removed"

Tags: discussion

is it possible to know on which Question or Answer the reputation change occured in case of "User was removed"

Example: https://askubuntu.com/users/739431?tab=reputation

there is 106 Reputation removed. Is it possible to know on which Question or ANswer was it?

Comment: See https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18646/lost-235-rep-due-to-user-removal which contains an answer to this question.

Comment: See this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238076/allow-seeing-which-posts-were-affected-by-removed-users